# Convolutional Neural Network keeps predicting the same class, are there any conventional problems that it may have?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

The programs supposed to train on images of ten fruits and learn to classify them. For the xtest data set it does just fine, with. perfect accuracy but when it comes to me handing it 1 random image to predict, it keeps guessing avacado.

```
def sorted_correctly(add = list):
    try:
        add.remove(".DS_Store")
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
        aplhanum_key = lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split("([0-9]+)",key)]
        return sorted(add ,key=aplhanum_key)

names = ["apple","avocado","banana","cherry","kiwi","mango","orange","pineapple","strawberries","watermelon"]
num_classes = len(names)

def create_data(Dir):
    global names
    img_data_list = []
    fruits = sorted_correctly(os.listdir(Dir))
    labels = []
    unexpected = []
    for fruit in fruits:
        img_list = sorted_correctly(os.listdir(Dir + "/" + fruit))
        for img in img_list:
            try:
                input_img = cv2.imread(Dir + "/" +  fruit + "/" + img)
                input_img_resize = cv2.resize(input_img,(IMG_COLS,IMG_ROWS))
            except Exception as e:
                unexpected.append(img)
            else:
                img_data_list.append(input_img_resize)
                labels.append(names.index(fruit))
       
    img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
    img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
    img_data /= 255
    labels = np.ones((len(img_data)),dtype='int64') #delete if problems arise
    y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels,len(names)) 
    return img_data,y

def create_prediction_data(Dir):
    img_list = sorted_correctly(os.listdir(Dir))
    img_data_list = []
    for image in img_list:
        try: 
            input_img = cv2.imread(Dir +"/" + image)
            input_img_resize = cv2.resize(input_img,(IMG_COLS,IMG_ROWS))
        except:
            pass
        else:
            img_data_list.append(input_img_resize)
    img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
    imgs = img_data
    img_data = img_data.astype("float32")
    img_data /= 255
    return img_data,imgs


def randomize(x,y):  
    temp = list(zip(x,y))
    shuffle(temp)
    x,y = zip(*temp)
    return x,y

def unison_shuffled_copies(a, b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    p = np.random.permutation(len(a))
    return a[p], b[p]
```

`create_data` goes through a local directory and creates numpy array, `create_prediction_data` has a similar function.

```
print("Train:")
print(x_train.shape)
print("Test:")
print(x_test.shape)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(128,128,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(names),activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer='adadelta',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', #https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326065/cross-entropy-vs-sparse-cross-entropy-when-to-use-one-over-the-other
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=5,batch_size=8,validation_data=(x_test,y_test))

loss_train = history.history["loss"]
loss_val = history.history["val_loss"]

score = model.evaluate([x_test],y_test,batch_size=32)
print("Evaluated.")
print("Test lost:", score[0])
print("Test accuracy:", score[1])
prediction_images,m = create_prediction_data(PREDICTION_DIRECTION)
for i in range(len(prediction_images)):
    img = Image.fromarray(m[i],"RGB")
    img.show()
    img = prediction_images[i]
    img = np.reshape(img,(1,128,128,3))
    prediction = np.argmax(model.predict(img))
    print(names[prediction])
```

Test accuracy is 1.

I've tried arbitrary pictures like a blank screen but it keeps predicting avocados. I've noticed that when I transform the pictures to an array and use the arrays to show them, they slightly turn bluish, may that be it? The number the pictures for each fruit is the same in x_train.

Also, `img_data = img_data.astype('float32')` if I show the image, it turns completely unrecognizable, may that be a problem? This is my first CNN.

Comment: fyi, `global names` is superfluous if you don't make any assignments to `names` inside the function.

Comment: All your labels are the same, as you overwrote the labels list with np.ones.